# When appending to a file, does bash keep that file in memory

Tags: bash, python, logrotate, redirection

I have a long running python program that logs to a file.

I start program and let it run in the background

```sh
python my-process.py >> /var/log/my_log.log  2>&1 &
```

The free memory slowly declines until logrotate rotates the log file. Memory is freed up, and the process repeats itself.

Does the free memory decline because when I append (`>>`) to the log file, it keeps the entire log file in memory?

I imagine adding a `maxsize` property to my logrotate config will keep memory freed up, but I'm also wondering if there is a better way to handle this.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the python program that's eating your memory?

Comment: I've done a _lot_ of investigating of the python program and haven't found a memory leak (though doesn't mean I haven't missed something). Since the memory is almost entirely freed up when `my_log.log` is rotated, I'm leaning toward it being an issue of the logfile being kept in memory

Comment: Did you use iostat or similar tools to capture some data? This seems like a simple filesystem I/O issue.